# Nodejs openshift app deployed code not working

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am working on nodejs app,i wrote server listening code,then i deployed code into openshift hosting,there i am getting 503 response,in local if i run this code it is properly working.

code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');


var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you pass the `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` variable? 
Quite often the problem is that the nodejs application is listening on IP `127.0.0.1` like in this case, but should on `0.0.0.0`. 
If that doesn't help please provide more details on how you created the application in OpenShift.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tricks that might help determine what the issue is.  The first way I approach it is to ssh into the OpenShift cartridge.  Assuming the name of your application is hello_world:

```
rhc ssh -a hello_world
```

Once inside, type:

```
lsof -i | grep node
```

This should list out the running node processes along with the ips and ports that each is listening to.  I have two node applications running, so my output looks like this:

```
node    23028     3389   11u  IPv4 518408054      0t0  TCP 127.6.158.129:8097 (LISTEN)
node    23028     3389   12u  IPv4 518408056      0t0  TCP 127.6.158.129:8080 (LISTEN)
```

So my node applications are listening on an actual ip address other than localhost.  My guess is that you will see something to this effect:

```
node    23028     3389   11u  IPv4 518408054      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Next, check your environment:

```
env | grep OPENSHIFT_NODEJS
```

Mine looks like this:

```
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT=8080
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP=127.6.158.129
```

So I can see that the OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT and OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP matches the output of my lsof statement above, so I'm all good.

I'm sure you will see a discrepancy after doing all this, and that will be your clue.