# NodeJS OpenShift app IP address environment variable missing

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am trying to deploy a NodeJS app to OpenShift and although all the deployment seems to function correctly and it looks like it's running, it seems like it's listening to the incorrect IP.

Every single tutorial instructs me to listen to `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` but using console.log I discovered that this variable is not set.

NodeJS Openshift official example starting point uses it:

https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex/blob/master/server.js

Another question on this subject suggests the same:
[Nodejs openshift app deployed code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966124/nodejs-openshift-app-deployed-code-not-working)

Anyone who has used OpenShift 3 knows why I can't find the IP address/why those supposedly globally available/default environment variables are not available and how to fix this?

Comment: They were globally available in OpenShift v2, which still has a lot of blogs available but outdated. You can either set the variable yourself, or just set your code to listen on 0.0.0.0

Comment: There seems to be a lot of differences between v2 - v3 so it's been difficult to figure out what I actually need to do. Thank you for the assistance!!

Answer (score 0):

We are using NodeJS in OSE 3.2 and OCP 3.5, the only thing I could think of which we actively set was the port to listen to in the deployment configuration.

```
name: http
containerPort: 8082
protocol: TCP
```

This is under containers -> ports

Otherwise we haven't done anything actively. Our build is using the Docker-strategy with a Docker-file but it doesn't specify anything about IPs or Ports to open up.

Comment: I could not find this setting.. The interface I'm looking at is the application.. Link looks like this: console.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com/console/project/myprojectname/overview

Comment: Go to Applications - Deployments then find the deployment and edit the file. Inside the yaml you'll find containers and ports.

Comment: By now I ended up switching to Heroku and managed to much more quickly deploy the app there, but thanks for taking the time!